# Relationship between components of orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-equations

Can we say that for two orthonormal vectors $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{w}$ that their matched components squared sum to 1? I.e. $u_i^2 + w_i^2 = 1$.

It seems obvious if you think about a pair of 2-d vectors, if you use the right basis the two orthonormal vectors can always be written as (in the new basis) $ \tilde{\textbf{u}}=[1,0] $ and  $ \tilde{\textbf{w}}=[0,1] $. But I am having trouble coming up with a proof based off their orthonormality (here just in the 2-D case)

$ u_1^2 + u_2^2 = w_1^2 + w_2^2 = 1 $

and

$ u_1 w_1 + u_2 w_2 = 0$.

Comment: what about $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ ?

Comment: @mfl I understand that I might misunderstand the question. Anyway, orthonormal is orthogonal with unit norm, isn't it?

Comment: Still I'm puzzled by the "if you use the right basis". I mean, for any basis there is always a basis change to the canonical basis.

Comment: @Surb I assume it is a basis $\{a,b\}$ with $a\cdot a=b\cdot b=1$ and $a\cdot b=0.$

Comment: Hint: the transpose of an orthogonal matrix is also orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $u=(a,b)$ then $v=\pm k(-b,a)$ because they are orthogonal. Now, what does it mean to be unitary? (orthonormal.)